# Is there an easy (idiomatic) way to convert a java.lang.reflect.Method to a Scala function?

Tags: reflection, scala, scala-2.8

Can I retrieve a Method via reflection, somehow combine it with a target object, and return it as something that looks like a function in Scala (i.e. you can call it using parenthesis)? The argument list is variable. It doesn't have to be a "first-class" function (I've updated the question), just a syntactic-looking function call, e.g. f(args).

My attempt so far looks something like this (which technically is pseudo-code, just to avoid cluttering up the post with additional definitions):

```
class method_ref(o: AnyRef, m: java.lang.reflect.Method) {
    def apply(args: Any*): some_return_type = {
        var oa: Array[Object] = args.toArray.map { _.asInstanceOf[Object] }
        println("calling: " + m.toString + " with: " + oa.length)

        m.invoke(o, oa: _*) match  {
            case x: some_return_type => x;
            case u => throw new Exception("unknown result" + u);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above I was able to get past the compiler errors, but now I have a run-time exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

The example usage is something like:

```
  var f = ... some expression returning method_ref ...;
  ...
  var y = f(x) // looks like a function, doesn't it?
```

***UPDATE***

Changing the args:Any* to args:AnyRef* actually fixed my run-time problem, so the above approach (with the fix) works fine for what I was trying to accomplish. I think I ran into a more general issue with varargs here.

Comment: Oh... I missed the thing about the "easy". No, there isn't. There used to, but it was experimental and was dropped.

Comment: You could always explain _where_ you got the error, since the method_ref as you posted won't compile.

Comment: It actually looks like changing the Any* to AnyRef* fixed my problem, although I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not looking for a generic `invoke` that takes the method name--but rather, you want to capture a particular method on a particular object--and you don't want to get too deeply into manifests and such, I think the following is a decent solution:

```
class MethodFunc[T <: AnyRef](o: Object, m: reflect.Method, tc: Class[T]) {
  def apply(oa: Any*): T = {
    val result = m.invoke(o, oa.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]): _*)
    if (result.getClass == tc) result.asInstanceOf[T]
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected result " + result)
  }
}
```

Let's see it in action:

```
val s = "Hi there, friend"
val m = s.getClass.getMethods.find(m => {
  m.getName == "substring" && m.getParameterTypes.length == 2
}).get
val mf = new MethodFunc(s,m,classOf[String])

scala> mf(3,8)
res10: String = there
```

The tricky part is getting the correct type for the return value.  Here it's left up to you to supply it.  For example,if you supply `classOf[CharSequence]` it will fail because it's not the right class.  (Manifests are better for this, but you did ask for simple...though I think "simple to use" is generally better than "simple to code the functionality".)

Comment: In my case the return type is fixed, so that extra bit of complexity was not needed. I'm still puzzled by the varargs stuff. I see you threw in a "_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]" where I had "_.asInstanceOf[Object]".

Comment: @Alex: `AnyRef` is Scala for `Object`.  I use `Object` to denote "this is a Java-y thing here" and `AnyRef` to denote "this is a Scala-y thing there".

Answer (score 4):

Sure. Here's some code I wrote that add an interface to a function. It's not exactly what you want, but I think it can be adapted with few changes. The most difficult change is on `invoke`, where you'll need to change the invoked method by the one obtained through reflection. Also, you'll have to take care that the received method you are processing is `apply`. Also, instead of `f`, you'd use the target object. It should probably look something like this:

```
  def invoke(proxy: AnyRef, method: Method, args: Array[AnyRef]) = method match {
    case m if /* m is apply */ => target.getClass().getMethod("name", /* parameter type */).invoke(target, args: _*)
    case _ => /* ??? */
  }
```

Anyway, here's the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.{Proxy, InvocationHandler, Method}

class Handler[T, R](f: Function1[T, R])(implicit fm: Manifest[Function1[T, R]]) extends InvocationHandler {
  def invoke(proxy: AnyRef, method: Method, args: Array[AnyRef]) = method.invoke(f, args: _*)
  def withInterface[I](implicit m: Manifest[I]) = {
    require(m <:< manifest[Function1[T, R]] && m.erasure.isInterface)
    Proxy.newProxyInstance(m.erasure.getClassLoader(), Array(m.erasure), this).asInstanceOf[I]
  }
}

object Handler {
  def apply[T, R](f: Function1[T, R])(implicit fm: Manifest[Function1[T, R]]) = new Handler(f)
}
```

And use it like this:

```
trait CostFunction extends Function1[String, Int]
Handler { x: String => x.length } withInterface manifest[CostFunction]
```

The use of "manifest" there helps with syntax. You could write it like this:

```
Handler({ x: String => x.length }).withInterface[CostFunction] // or
Handler((_: String).length).withInterface[CostFunction]
```

One could also drop the manifest and use classOf instead with a few changes.

Comment: Yikes. There should be something simpler. Please see my updated question with what I've tried so far, which at this point compiles but fails at run-time.